# How to Loop through a specific column in a table

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba

New to Access VBA and need some assistance. I have a table with a boolean field I am trying to loop through to locate all of the "False" fields. Once located I want to display a messagebox containing the ID number and some basic information. My table is housed in a SQL database. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Easiest way is to create a query that contains this sub dataset you want, then just open that query as a record set and loop through it with a while statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use GetString. Here's an example

```
Public Sub MsgBoxActives()

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT CUSTOMERID, DISCOUNT FROM [Volume Rebate Customers] WHERE not [INACTIVE?];")

    MsgBox rs.GetString

End Sub
```